# Ошибка #1064 запросе SQL в phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Имеется таблица preliminary_schema:

[image]

Пытаюсь создать процедуру, которая добавляет запись в таблицу следующим образом:

1. если не имеется записей со значением поля player_mode, похожим на "Player", то добавляем в таблицу запись:

`INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player1', 0, 0)`.

2. если подобная запись имеется, то добавляем запись:

`INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player2', 0, 0)`.

Процедура следующего вида:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPlayer(new_name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM preliminary_schema WHERE player_mode LIKE 'Player%')
WHEN 0 THEN INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player1', 0, 0)
WHEN 1 THEN INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player2', 0, 0) 
END
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'WHEN 1 THEN INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player2', 0, 0)' на строке 5.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чего делаю не так ? Или как правильней оформить эту мысль в коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В CASE надо передавать переменную а не курсор. простыми словами. select в общем случае возвращает кучу записей из кучи полей. В CASE вам надо явно указать значение. см. ниже.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE AddPlayer(new_name VARCHAR(30))
    BEGIN
      DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0;
      SELECT COUNT(*) into c FROM preliminary_schema WHERE player_mode LIKE 'Player%';
      CASE (c)
          WHEN 0 THEN INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player1', 0, 0);
          WHEN 1 THEN INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'Player2', 0, 0);
          ELSE INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, 'PlayerX', 0, 0);
      END CASE;
    END;
```

хотя в вашем случае (хотя я и не знаю задумки), было бы симпатичнее сделать так:

```
 DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) into @c FROM preliminary_schema WHERE player_mode LIKE 'Player%';
INSERT INTO preliminary_schema VALUES (new_name, case c when 0 then 'Player1' when 1 then 'Player2' else 'PlayerX' end, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Процедура работает, но даже, если имеется уже запись, где значение поля `player_mode` похоже на 'Player%', всё равно создаётся запись со значением этого поля 'Player1'. Как сделать так, чтобы второй записью была запись со значением этого поля 'Player2' ?

Comment: немного поправил (+добавил вариант когда записей >1. иначе будет исключение)

Comment: Отлично, всё работает. Благодарю